# How to show all questions and answer inputs in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I made this models, urls, etc, but it doesn't show all questions/pertanyaan that I made. It also didn't save the answers/jawaban through database. Idk which one is having error. Here's my code, though :

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Pertanyaan
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import JawabanForm
from django.contrib import messages

@login_required
def get_jawabans(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        jawab_form = JawabanForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if jawab_form.is_valid():
            jawab_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Anda berhasil menjawab kuisioner')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Anda gagal menjawab kuisioner')
    else:
        jawab_form = JawabanForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'survey/kuisioner.html', {'jawab_form':jawab_form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Kuisioner(models.Model):
    judul = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    alias = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['judul']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.judul

class Pertanyaan(models.Model):
    kuisioner = models.ForeignKey(Kuisioner, related_name='pertanyaans', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pertanyaan = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pertanyaan

class Jawaban(models.Model):
    pertanyaan = models.ForeignKey(Pertanyaan, related_name='jawabans', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    jawab = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

urls.py inside survey app

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('kuisioner/', views.get_jawabans, name='get_jawabans')
]
```

urls.py in my project

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/', include('account.urls')),
    path('survey/', include('survey.urls')),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Jawaban

class JawabanForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Jawaban
        fields = ['pertanyaan', 'jawab']
```

It is working, but it showed up like this :
[Screenshot of the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Cxi.png)
I'm kinda new to this django, so Idk much about django's settings

EDIT :
This is my HTML file (I forgot to post it)

kuisioner.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Dashboard{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
{% for pertanyaan in pertanyaans %}
<form action = "{% url 'get_jawabans' %}"method = "post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ jawab_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you also share the HTML file from where you sent the post request? Also, is it showing your intended success message once you submit the request?

Comment: Ooh ye. I forgot to post my html file

Comment: And yes. It's showing that success message appeared after submit, but it didn't save in database

Comment: Is there any path registration with the name 'get_jawabans'?, because I see this name in your form's action attribute but nowhere in your URL patterns. If you intend to call the 'get_pertanyaans' function in your POST request then your form's action should map to the path name 'get_pertanyaans'.

Comment: I edited get_pertanyaans as get_jawabans. I forgot to change it in this forum

Answer (score 0):

In the POST method of your function. You should use the redirect method so the form doesn't post twice and move to another page or the same page.

By looking at your code, the data should be saved (You should check the Admin page for saved data). However, you didn't redirect to any page, so it remains on the same page.

Update the code like below:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect    

@login_required
def get_jawabans(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        jawab_form = JawabanForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if jawab_form.is_valid():
            jawab_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Anda berhasil menjawab kuisioner')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('success/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Anda gagal menjawab kuisioner')
    else:
        jawab_form = JawabanForm(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'survey/kuisioner.html', {'jawab_form':jawab_form})
```

Create an entry for `success/` URL in the app urls.py file for the above redirect.